# How to make a variable inside a function be available outside?

Tags: php, variables

I can't seem to get the array on `$sql_result_array` be available out of the function.

```
function function_name($query, $table_name){
    global $connection;
$sql_query = " SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE name = '{$query}' ";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql_query, $connection);
$sql_result_array = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result);
}

function_name($value1, $value2);
print_r($sql_result_array); // (outputs) Undefined variable: sql_result_array
```

Any suggestion on how to get that array available outside the function?

Comment: The first thing you should do is stop using mysql_query and look into the PDO object instead.

Comment: In simple terms, what you have to do is "do something" with the return value of the method. You have to e.g. explicitly capture it into a variable. Also, `echo print_r(...)` doesn't make much sense. Just `print_r`.

Comment: The main issue is your failure to understand what `return` keyword does here.  You simply need to assign the result of the function call to a variable.

Comment: It's a return value - just assign it a variable when calling the function.

Comment: ok tnx for the info. was a bit careless there

Comment: All that downvoting and/or closing down doesn't seem really necessary. The question is quite clear and it seems like a fair question to educate oneself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either do

```
print_r(function_name($value1, $value2));
```

or

```
$sql_result_array = function_name($value1, $value2)
print_r($sql_result_array);
```

The general idea here, is that any variable you declare inside of a function is ONLY available inside of that function.  So if you have

```
function a() {
    $i = 5;
    return $i;
}
```

OUTSIDE of that function, `$i` does not exist.  Or if it DOES exist, setting `$i` to 5 INSIDE that function, won't change the value of `$i` OUTSIDE of that function.  This is good because otherwise, you would have to use unique variable names EVERYWHERE, otherwise you would never know if a value got changed somewhere else.

We `return $i` so that is we want to use that value outside of the function, we can.  But we have to either assign it

```
$other_variable = a();
```

or use it directly

```
do_something_else(a())
```